# Arquivo de internalização, como criar?

Tags: android, android-studio

Boa tarde, alguém sabe como criar o arquivo de internalização no Android ?

Quero criar uma strings.xml(en), obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De forma bem sucinta, você só precisa criar um diretório, por exemplo `values-en` dentro do `res`. O `en` significa que é English. Poderia ser `fr`, Francês, e assim por diante.

Desta forma para cada chave, você faz a tradução.

Exemplo:

**res/values**

```
<string name="title_settings">Configurações</string>
```

**res/values-en**

```
<string name="title_settings">Configurations</string>
```

Leia mais aqui sobre [Compatibilidade com diferentes dispositivos](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/languages.html?hl=pt-br).

Comment: Quando eu vou em res > New>Directory adiciono o nome, ele carrega e fecha, ai quando vou procurar o diretório eu não encontro e se tento criar novamente fala que já existe

Comment: Vai na pasta onde está localizada seu projeto e crie por lá mesmo. Pode até copiar e colar o strings.xml. Ai você voltará na IDE e já estará lá.